# How to join multiple dataframes in R but exclude some columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reduce

I have 12 dataframes in total with differing number of rows and columns. For example the first one looks like:

```
   id age   bmi  surgerytype1 surgerytype2 surgerytype3 telangiectasia_G1
1 RQ00001-2  62 29.00                    0                    1                    0                      
2 RQ00002-0  47 21.72                    1                    0                    0                      
3 RQ00004-9  56 28.04                    1                    0                    0                      
4 RQ00005-4  63 31.23                    1                    0                    0                      
5 RQ00006-5  68 21.94                    1                    0                    0                      
6 RQ00007-7  55 22.84                    1                    0                    0 
                     
  cvd rt_axilla **telangiectasia_24_logistic_resid**
1   1         0                        1.6703390
2   0         0                       -0.2387378
3   0         0                       -0.3638869
4   0         0                       -0.4635757
5   0         0                       -0.3235804
6   1         0                       -0.3815662
```

Most of the dataframes follows these  formats  but they may have an extra column or one less column. In addition, they may have slightly different number of rows. I want to merge all these data-frames together by 'id'. All of these data-frames have 'id' in column 1 which should be similar BUT NOT identical across all data-frames.

In addition the columns I am particularly interested in, is the id column and last columns e.g. telangiectasia_24_logistic_resid (from the above data-frame - also highlighted in bold). All the last columns from every one of the 12 dataframes I am interested in and want to retain.

I want my final dataframe to have the id in the first column and then the last columns of the other dataframes e.g.

```
id  last_colfrom_dataframe_1 last_colfrom_dataframe_2 last_colfrom_dataframe_3 etc...
RQ00001-2     <-- DATA/VALUES  -->
RQ00002-0 
RQ00004-9 
RQ00005-4 
RQ00006-5 
RQ00007-7
```

I don't mind doing a full merge but this will retain extra columns i am not intrested in (e.g. age   bmi  surgerytype1). I just want id and the last columns from all the dataframes.

I have tried this merge as well as full_join command in R but it does not work.

```
residual_tox <- merge(resid_ID_telang_g1, resid_ID_atrophyg1, resid_ID_atrophyg2, resid_ID_NipRetract_G1, NipRetract_G2_resid, resid_ID_oedema1, Odema_G2_resid_ID, Indur_G1_resid_ID, Indur_outside_resid_ID, Indur_G2_resid_ID, arm_lymoG1_ID, late_hyperpig_ID, by = "id")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `id` values are **different** in all of the data frames? If so, I wouldn't think of this as merging as there is no matching going on. Maybe `dplyr::bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, ...)`?

Comment: I would say they are 99% similar - it's just  some data-frames may not include a particular ID because there was no value for the phenotype, therefore it was excluded and that resulting ID was missing but the ID may be present in another dataframe because it has a particular phenotype value. Therefore, I want all data frames joined together - it will be just an NA for the missing phenotype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could approach this by making a list of dataframes, each including just the ID column and the column you want to keep, and then using this list make the merged dataframe using the `Reduce` function.

Suppose your dataframes are called `df1`, `df2`, `df3` as follows.  Each has an `id` column, a column I want to discard and the last column I want to keep.  Note the IDs don't necessarily overlap.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2), x=c("a", "b"), a=c("a", "b"))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(2,3), y=c("a", "b"), b=c("cc", "ss"))
df3 <- data.frame(id=c(1,3), z=c("a", "b"), c=c("22", "1"))
```

Now make a list including each dataframe, but only its first and last column.

```
dfl <-  lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), function(d) d[, c("id", tail(names(d),1))])
```

Then the `Reduce` function can take this list, and sequentially apply `merge` until they are all combined:

```
Reduce(function(x1, x2) merge(x1, x2, all=TRUE, by="id") ,  dfl)
```

Which gives the output I think you expect:

```
  id    a    b    c
1  1    a <NA>   22
2  2    b   cc <NA>
3  3 <NA>   ss    1
```

Comment: Sorry to  be stupid, but what is x, y and z? And what is  a b and c? In the first example above?

Comment: Your question said you only wanted to keep the last column from each data frame (with the ID).  So I made up some column names for my small example.  x, y and z are the middle columns I don't want to keep.  a, b and c are the names of the last columns in my dataframes.

Comment: You only need to start from the line `dfl <- ...`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get an error: 'Error in d[, c("id", tail(names(d), 1))] : incorrect number of dimensions' when doing the dfl1 <- ....

Comment: i can't diagnose this without seeing samples of your data frames and the full command you are trying to use

Comment: residual_toxicities <-  lapply(list(resid_ID_telangiectasia_g1, resid_ID_atrophyg1, resid_ID_atrophyg2, resid_ID_NippleRetraction_G1, NippleRetraction_G2_resid, resid_ID_oedema1, Odema_G2_resid_ID, Induration_G1_resid_ID, Induration_outside_resid_ID, Induration_G2_resid_ID, arm_lymohoedemaG1_ID), function(d) d[, c("id", tail(names(d),1))])

Comment: I just inserted my data-frame names in the lapply list bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239134/discussion-between-george-savva-and-hkj3).